# How can I remove an individual parameter from a Symfony2 request object

Tags: symfony

I have the following request object and would like to remove 'email_suffix' from a controller before binding to a form. Is this possible?

```
public 'request' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[8]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array
          'registration' => 
            array
              'email' => string 's' (length=1)
              'email_suffix' => string 'y.com' (length=5)
              'password' => string '1234' (length=4)
              '_token' => string '967d99ba9f955aa67eb9eb004bd331151d816d06' (length=40)
          'product_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'product_description' => string '12 month membership' (length=19)
          'product_price' => string '6.99' (length=4)
```

I have tried         `$request->request->remove("registration[email_suffix]");`

I can do $request->request->remove("registration") - this works.

For now, I am doing this:

```
$requestReg = $request->request->get('registration');
$requestReg['email'] = $requestReg['email'].'@'.$requestReg['email_suffix'];
unset($requestReg['email_suffix']);
$request->request->set('registration',$requestReg);
```

Comment: Did you mean `$request->attributes->get(...)`?

Comment: Your approach (getting the registration parameter, deleting the member you don´t want and saving it again) seems fine to me. What is the problem?

Comment: @CarlosGranados I just wanted to know is there was a cleaner way to do it. Apparently there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if your call `$request->request` is typo.

You should operate with `$request->attributes` which represents `ParameterBag` class.

If you'll go through methods in [ParameterBag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php) you'll see that there is no way to unset variable inside array.

Comment: Thanks. $request->request does the same thing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can get parameters, unset whatever you want and use replace() method to update parameter bag... but upvoting, because this answer leaded me to what I wanted

Answer (score 13):

There's the possibility to add and to remove the parameters from the request object in symfony2.
You have to look at [ParameterBag Component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php), there's such the method called `remove($key)`, that's what you need.

So the solution for your request would be like this, if you call it from controller object:

```
$this->get('request')->query->remove('email_suffix');
```

Comment: Nice one and works for Laravel 5.1 (since it extends Symfony's Request class). Thanks!

Comment: This is the one that worked for Symfony 2.7;  `query`, not `attributes`.
In my case this was a query string ("?refresh") I was intercepting in a kernel event listener and wanted to remove it before the controller was called.