# Symfony2 : how to remove request parameter?

Tags: php, symfony, post, parameters

I have this parameters submitted by a form :

```
myform[field1]: 'text1'
myform[field2]: 'text2'
myform[field3]: 'text3'
```

Under condition, `myform[field3]` must not be validated, so i want to remove it.

How can I remove the parameter `myform[field3]`?

I try a lot of things without success like :

```
$request->attributes->remove("field3");
$request->request->remove("field3");
$request->request->remove("myform[field3]");
```

How can I remove this parameter?

**Update**

In fact `$request->request->remove("myform");` is working, but remove all parameters. Is it possible to remove only an element of the array?

Comment: `$request->request->remove($key)` should work as per the documentation: http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_remove See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807888/how-can-i-remove-an-individual-parameter-from-a-symfony2-request-object/27445108#27445108

Comment: This might look stupid and is one very simple guess but have you tried `$request->request->remove(array('myform' => 'field3'))`?

Comment: As answer Peter Bailey - dno't set constraints for this field in your FromType. If you remove this field from request, then $form->getData() don't contain this field.

Comment: @D4V1D thanks but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. What you're really looking for is conditional validation, and there are several options for that

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups